# PowerApps: 3 keys were specified, but 4 values were provided

Tags: sql, powerapps

I get this questions title when trying to update a record in Microsoft PowerApps + SQL server. This particular table happens to have 3 out of four fields as keys. I can confirm that I have permissions on my user to update the record. New records can be created just fine, just not updating ones. Very confused on how to correct this issue as it was working fine prior to the weekend.

Comment: What expression are you using when you get this error? I tried in the same scenario with both forms (using `SubmitForm`) and with a `Patch` call, and in both cases the updates were successful.

Comment: Also tried both SubmitForm and Patch. Both gave same error. I'll clarify that this is utilizing an Azure SQL database connection.

Comment: Hmmm...and apparently only on this one table. I just don't understand what the error message is trying to tell me.

Comment: Weird... can you post the the table definition?

Comment: Resolved. One of the fields that we were trying to update was part of the SQL table Composite Key, which obviously (now) will not work in an Update query but fine in a Create query. I changed the Composite Key to not use the field in question and everything is working as expected now.

Comment: Glad to see it resolved. Can you post this comment as an answer, and accept it, so that if other people have the same issue they find it?

Answer (score 0):

This problem occurs when any of the columns that make up the composite key contains a comma, so you can solve it by replacing those in the underlying model.

It could be that PowerApps splits the composite key at each comma in a CSV-fashion, resulting in the additional field.